# Keep lines with multiple matches from file grep

Tags: command-line, grep

I have two files:

the `query.txt`

```
i1  
i2
i3  
i4
```

and the `subject.txt`

```
2   i1  i2  p
3   i2  i5  p
1   i3  i4  p
2   i3  i4  p
1   i5  i1  p
1   i4  i2  p
```

I need to get the lines from `subject.txt` that have entries from `query.txt` in columns 2 and 3 of `subject.txt` (in any order), and I want to get rid of lines of `subject.txt` that has an entry from `query.txt` only in one of columns of `subject.txt`.

So I want to keep only:

```
2   i1  i2  p
1   i3  i4  p
1   i4  i2  p
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have logic that is column/field based, [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is a better tool to use:

```sh
awk '
    NR == FNR {q[$1] = 1; next}
    $2 in q && $3 in q
' query.txt subject.txt
```